# IIS Express site dosnt start on VS F5

Tags: iis-express, episerver

Using Episerver in VS 2017

My site runs in IIS Express. When I start the project from VS in Chrome, I get the default IIS Screen (The blue screen with IIS info) - so IIS starts, but the site does not launch. If I reload the browser, the site launches.

Here is my site definition in the applicationhost.config:

```
      <site name="MySite" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\mysite-episerver\src\MySite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:mysite.mydomain.com" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

**Update**

Looking at the log:

```
Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
Version: 1.0
Date: 2018-05-25 18:09:24
Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-05-25 18:09:24 127.0.0.1 GET / - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 13991
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /personal/ - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 6389
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/styles/main.css v=636627702363674333 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 37
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/fonts/stylesheet.css - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 29
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /EPiServer.Forms/DataSubmit/GetFormInitScript formGuid=6bd570d3-3e91-447f-903e-566e9d9f9468&formLanguage=en 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 171
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /WebResource.axd d=TzRGlCddaaqtz0Im2nSJhBlH3P1Fze7Czb4HaEn0ZkkpUFjLB2tREFUTizpsCAfxQQOQDZCZqUiBZLAo7l7EhsGTwsuUFnRXRabRz6n3XcvVK2Bd0VQe-ZDaVHtSCoc3paD6qdAAJwaIPHOv9FJMVOt6_eqfG_NNb1zepx_9qUk1&t=636601600300000000 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 81
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/scripts/sticky-header.js v=636627702363754120 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 130
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/scripts/main.js v=636627702363724200 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 149
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/scripts/forms.js v=636627702363704257 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 165
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /siteassets/settings/logo_mysiteusa.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 171
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/profile.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 185
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /siteassets/image-blocks/785x650.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 181
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /siteassets/heros/180800277.jpg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 294
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/BG-Pattern.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 70
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /siteassets/image-and-text-blocks/bbb.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 217
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/chevron.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 65
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /siteassets/image-and-text-blocks/bestmysite.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 255
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /siteassets/settings/logo_ehl.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 253
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/jumplink.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 89
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /siteassets/settings/footer-mountains.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 112
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/footer_linkedin.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 38
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/icon_quotation.png - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 37
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/footer_twitter.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 76
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/doublearrow.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 173
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/footer_facebook.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 68
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/mobilephone.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 43
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/email.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 115
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/footer_youtube.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 200
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/doublearrow-white.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 105
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /dist/images/worldwide.svg - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/dist/styles/main.css?v=636627702363674333 200 0 0 115
2018-05-25 18:09:31 127.0.0.1 GET /util/LiveMonitor/Tracking/Index contentId=34&languageId=en&r=0.6407196012207004&referrer= 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 131
2018-05-25 18:09:32 127.0.0.1 GET /util/LiveMonitor/Tracking/Index contentId=34&languageId=en&r=0.5590579783850214&referrer= 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/personal/ 200 0 0 565
2018-05-25 18:09:36 127.0.0.1 GET /login/ - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 223
2018-05-25 18:09:36 127.0.0.1 GET /util/LiveMonitor/Tracking/Index contentId=271&languageId=en&r=0.29442535680181825&referrer= 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/login/ 200 0 0 55
2018-05-25 18:09:36 127.0.0.1 GET /util/LiveMonitor/Tracking/Index contentId=271&languageId=en&r=0.21276262992917028&referrer= 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/login/ 200 0 0 578
2018-05-25 18:09:52 127.0.0.1 POST /login/post/ - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/login/ 302 0 0 443
2018-05-25 18:09:52 127.0.0.1 GET /login/post/mysiteusa/cms/ - 80 admin 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/login/ 404 0 0 506
2018-05-25 18:09:52 127.0.0.1 GET /util/LiveMonitor/Tracking/Index contentId=9&languageId=en&r=0.2522424054704595&referrer=http%3A//mysite.mydomain.com/login/ 80 admin 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/login/post/%2Fmysiteusa%2Fcms%2F 200 0 0 37
2018-05-25 18:09:52 127.0.0.1 GET /util/LiveMonitor/Tracking/Index contentId=9&languageId=en&r=0.9305181288066644&referrer=http%3A//mysite.mydomain.com/login/ 80 admin 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/login/post/%2Fmysiteusa%2Fcms%2F 200 0 0 42
2018-05-25 18:09:52 127.0.0.1 GET /epiutil/images/quicknav/quicknav-arrow.png - 80 admin 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/66.0.3359.181+Safari/537.36 http://mysite.mydomain.com/epiutil/styles/quicknavigator.css 200 0 0 57
```

[image]

```
<WebProjectProperties>
      <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
      <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
      <DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>
      <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
      <IISUrl>http://goalaskausa.mydelphic.com</IISUrl>
      <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
      <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
      <CustomServerUrl>
      </CustomServerUrl>
      <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
    </WebProjectProperties>
```

UseIIS keeps getting reset to true. I think whats happening is that its hitting IIS, not IIS express. Then when I refresh it hits IIS express.

Comment: If possible, read IIS log files to confirm the behaviors in the second paragraph. If the files show a different conversation, then you need to check the browser setting.

Comment: I dont really understand your suggestion. IIS log points to correct domain and port. Which browser settings?

Comment: If we translate what you described to page access, then IIS log files should first show an access to `iisstart.htm` and then an access to your site's default page. Please check the files to see if you are able to observe the exact sequence. You should paste the relevant log entries as part of your question, as that can help others understand better what happened.

Comment: I dont see iisstart in the log. Updating question...

Comment: "2018-05-25 18:09:24 127.0.0.1 GET / - 80" As IIS default document feature might serve `iisstart.htm` for requests on `/`, you might go to the site content folder and delete `iisstart.htm` if it exists. Then try to reproduce the issue once again.

Comment: Please consider explaining what techniques you are using. Your logs are `IIS` but the topic and config are `IIS Express`. Please add the data in the `<WebProjectProperties>` from your .csproj-file.

Comment: Those logs are IIS Express.